# How to use the result of a variable inside a pattern expression within the same line in BASH?

Tags: bash

I would like to run the following in one line:

```
var=$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15)
echo "${var// /_}"
```

which takes the first 15 characters of a string only and replaces spaces with underscores. I have tried:

```
echo "${$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15)// /_}"
```

but it says `Bad Substitution`. What is wrong?

Comment: `var="$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15 | tr " " "_")"`?

Comment: life is too short to worry about this ;-) . Why not `var=$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15); echo "${var// /_}"` (note the `;`). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform variable substitution on something which isn't a variable.

```sh
var="String with spaces inside we want to remove."
var=${var:0:15}
echo "${var// /_}"
```

Sometimes you wish there was a way to nest variable substitutions, but alas, there isn't.

Demo: https://ideone.com/cL1PYo

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
var=$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | sed -E 's/(.{15}).*/\1/; y/ /_/')
```

Output:

```
String_with_spa
```

Answer (score 1):

Your double variable substitution command will work with `zsh`, but not `bash`:

```
# bash - bad substitution
echo "${$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15)// /_}"

-bash: ${$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15)// /_}: bad substitution

# zsh - works
zsh

~ % echo "${$(echo "String with spaces inside we want to remove." | cut -c1-15)// /_}"
String_with_spa
```